# Javascript: Rock, paper, scissors game only returning tie

Tags: javascript

I am completing this Rock, Paper, Scissors game in javascript.  I'm trying to clean up some code but when I run this, I am only getting ties.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

```js
function getComputerChoice(){
    const val = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*val.length);
    return val[random];
}

function playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection){
    if (computerSelection ==="rock" && playerSelection ==="paper"  || computerSelection ==="scissors" && playerSelection ==="rock" || computerSelection ==="paper" && playerSelection ==="scissors")
    {
        return "You Win!";
    } else if (computerSelection ==="scissors" && playerSelection ==="paper" || computerSelection ==="rock" && playerSelection ==="scissors" || computerSelection ==="paper" && playerSelection === "rock")//
    {
        return "You Lose!";    
    } else {
        return "Tie";
    
    }
    }

let playerSelection1 = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
let computerSelection= getComputerChoice();
let playerSelection= playerSelection1.toLowerCase();
console.log(playerSelection);
console.log(getComputerChoice());
console.log (playRound());
```

Comment: You didn't pass the 2 required arguments to the `playRound` function, so they'll both be undefined and equal

Comment: `playRound()` expects two arguments. You're calling it with none.

Comment: You're also having the computer randomly choose an option *twice*, using one value and logging the other one.

Comment: Just because the variables in- and outside of the function have the same name doesn't make them the same variables. The arguments defined for `playRound()` "overwrite" ([Variable Shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) the outer ones. So either remove the parameters from the function defintion or pass them to `playRound()`

Answer (score 3):

You do not pass the variables for the 'playRound' function

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't receive any parameter. Also on your console logs, you generate a different computer choice.

```js
function getComputerChoice(){
    const val = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random()*val.length);
    return val[random];
}

function playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection){
    if (computerSelection ==="rock" && playerSelection ==="paper"  || computerSelection ==="scissors" && playerSelection ==="rock" || computerSelection ==="paper" && playerSelection ==="scissors")
    {
        return "You Win!";
    } else if (computerSelection ==="scissors" && playerSelection ==="paper" || computerSelection ==="rock" && playerSelection ==="scissors" || computerSelection ==="paper" && playerSelection === "rock")//
    {
        return "You Lose!";    
    } else {
        return "Tie";
    
    }
    }

let playerSelection1 = prompt("Rock, Paper, or Scissors");
let computerSelection= getComputerChoice();
let playerSelection= playerSelection1.toLowerCase();
console.log(playerSelection);
console.log(computerSelection);
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

Comment: Please don't add an answer on such obvious "typo" questions. There's a close vote option for that exact case.